# How JVM collect ThreadDump underhood

Tags: java, jvm, perf, jvm-hotspot, jvmti

Please explain how JVM collect ThreadDump underhood.
I don't understand how it collectons stack traces of threads that are off-CPU (wait disk IO,Network,non-voluntary context switches). 
For example, linux perf  collect info only about on-CPU threads(which use CPU-cycles)

Comment: The JVM is responsible for _starting_ those off-CPU threads.  It can track them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll take HotSpot JVM as an example.

The JVM maintains the list of all Java threads: for each thread it has a corresponding VM structure. A thread can be in one of the following states depending on its execution context (HotSpot knows the current state of each thread, because it's responsible for switching states):

- `in_Java` - a thread is executing Java code, either in the interpreter or in a JIT-compiled method;
- `in_vm` - a thread is inside a VM runtime function;
- `in_native` - a thread is running a native method in JNI context;
- there are also transitional states, but let's skip them for simplicity.

An off-cpu thread can have only

- `in_native` state: all socket I/O, disk I/O, and otherwise blocking operations are performed only in native code;
- `in_vm` state, when a thread is blocked on a VM mutex.

Whenever the JVM calls a native method or acquires a contended mutex, it stores the last Java frame pointer into the `Thread` structure.

Now the crucial part: **HotSpot JVM obtains a thread dump only at a [safepoint](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html)**.

When you ask for a thread dump, the JVM requests a stop-the-world pause. All threads in `in_Java` state are stopped at the nearest safepoint, where the JVM knows how to walk the stack.

Threads in `in_native` state are not stopped, but they don't need to. HotSpot knows their last Java frame, because the pointer is stored in a `Thread` structure. Knowing the top Java frame, the JVM can find its caller, then the caller of the caller, and so on.

[image: Stack walking]

What important here is that the Java part of the stack is "frozen", no matter what the native method does. The top part of the stack (native) can change back and forth, while the bottom part (Java) remains immutable. It cannot change, since the JVM checks for a pending safepoint operation on every switch from `in_native` to `in_Java`: if a native method returns, and the VM is currently running a stop-the-world operation, current thread blocks until the operation ends.

So, getting a thread dump involves

1. Stopping all `in_Java` and `in_vm` threads at a safepoint;
2. Walking through the global list of threads maintained by the JVM;
3. If a thread is running native method, its top Java frame is stored in a thread structure; if a thread is running Java code, its top frame corresponds to the currently executing Java method.
4. Each frame has a link to the previous frame, so given the top frame, the JVM can construct the whole stack trace to the bottom.

Comment: Awesome answer, as usual Thanks Andrey! May be you describe how work AsyncGetCallTrace ? :)